# Erro when deploying to heroku my react app

Tags: reactjs, heroku, proxy, fetch

I create an app with react, this app has a few fetch that gets data from mongodb. when I finished the app and everything was working I deployed to heroku but I had the error of Invalid host Header, so after looking for a solution i found out that i should erase `proxy://localhost:5000` from `package.json` in client folder. Now you can see the app in heroku but in heroku and in my pc the fetch are returning the index.html. all of them. If i put the proxy back the fecth in my computer work but in heroku appears again de Invalid host Header error. Please help me

here is the error[cannot find module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aLoO.png)

this is my scripts in `package.json` in root folder`"scripts": {
    "server": " nodemon server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": " concurrently \"npm run server\" \"cd client && npm start\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  }`

this is in the `server.js` that is outside of src

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Static folder
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

I created a Procfile like others say to do

```
web: node my-app/server.js
```

and here is my github repository
[github repository](https://github.com/manelbrioude/MYitinerary)